# How is this $\log$ equation solved?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I tried solving this log equation:

$$4-\cos(-1)=c+5\ln(c-1)$$
$$4-\cos(1)-c=\ln(c-1)^5$$
$$e^{4-\cos(1)-c}=(c-1)^5$$

I got stuck there and don't know how to extract the $c$ from the exponent of $e$.

Comment: Not all problems have nice [closed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression) solutions. You can show that the [graph of the curve is decreasing on for $c > 1$ and goes from positive to negative](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4-Cos%5B-1%5D-c-5*Log%5Bc-1%5D). One way to get the solution is to perform [bisection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) on an interval containing the root (e.g., lower bound $a=1.5$ and upper bound $b=3$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no closed form solution, but one with the Lambert W-Function.

$$
4-\cos(-1)=c+5\ln(c-1)\\
\sqrt[5]{\exp{(4-\cos(-1))}}=(c-1)e^{c/5} = (c-1)e^{(c-1)/5}e^{1/5} 
$$
Let $(c-1) = x$ then we have
$$
e^{-\frac15 x}
= x\frac{e^{1/5}}{\sqrt[5]{\exp{(4-\cos(-1))}}} 
$$
Now use the Lambert W-Function. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) gives the explicit example that the   solution to
$$
e^{- b x} = a x$$
is
$x = \frac1b W \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)$
So we obtain

$$
c = 1+x = 1 + 5 W\left(\frac{\sqrt[5]{\exp{(4-\cos(-1))}}}{5 e^{1/5}}\right)
= 1 + 5 W\left(\frac{{\exp{\left(\frac{3-\cos(-1)}{5}\right)}}}{5 }\right) \approx 2.26891$$

Wolframalpha will give this result with [this link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%20%2B%205*%28lambert%20w%20function%28exp%28%283-cos%28-1%29%29%2F5%29%2F5%29%29).

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot use Lambert function (it would be a pitty), only numerical method would make the job.

Consider that you look for the zero('s) of function
$$f(c)=c+5 \log (c-1)-4+\cos (1)$$ Its derivatives
$$f'(c)=\frac{5}{c-1}+1 \qquad \text{and} \qquad f''(c)=-\frac{5}{(c-1)^2} < 0 \qquad \forall c$$ Since you look for $c > 1$ because ot the logarithm, $f(c)$ is an incresing function and there is a single root.

Now, using inspection $f(2)=\cos (1)-2<0$ but $f(3)=-1+5 \log (2)+\cos (1)>0$. To get an *approximation*, make a series expansion around $c=2$; this will be
$$f(c)=(\cos (1)-2)+6 (c-2)-\frac{5}{2} (c-2)^2+\frac{5}{3} (c-2)^3-\frac{5}{4}
   (c-2)^4+O\left((c-2)^5\right)$$ Now, using series reversion
$$c=2+t+\frac{5 t^2}{12}+\frac{5 t^3}{72}-\frac{5 t^4}{576}+O\left(t^5\right)\qquad \text{with} \qquad t=\frac{f(c)+2-\cos (1)}{6} $$
Make $f(c)=0$ to get
$$c=\frac{14265617-1294768 \cos (1)+39820 \cos (2)-400 \cos (3)-5 \cos
   (4)}{5971968}\approx 2.26891$$ while the "exact" solution, given by Newton method is ... **the same !!**